# MS-RL License section 3A

Tags: open-source, licensing

Sometime ago the question [Ms-RL - Explanation needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491099/1153583) was posted. The only answer given relating to section 3A was:-

> *3(A) Reciprocal Grants- For any **file** you distribute that contains code
>   from the software (in source code or binary format), you must provide
>   recipients the source code to that file along with a copy of this
>   license, which license will govern that file. You may license other
>   files that are entirely your own work and do not contain code from the
>   software under any terms you choose.*
>
> Translation: For each file that uses files under the Ms-RL, you need to 
>   provide the source and a copy of the license.

What is not clear to me is the definition of the word **file**. If I make use of a DLL licensed under Ms-RL (such as a visual component/control) and I ship my DLL/EXE along with their DLL and their source code is that sufficient to satisfy the license? If I now zip the files or compose an MSI do I now have to include my source code too as the zip/MSI **file** contains the binary of their DLL?

Comment: Curious why the original question that I quoted is not also off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're shipping the component itself, just make sure that the source of it is made available "somewhere" and it's properly defined the license being used (in this case the Ms-RL), just a txt somewhere saying "the component can be found at xxx"

It's not a viral license so using this doesn't affect the rest of your project

Comment: Commonly viral is a term used to describe *reciprocal* licenses (and make them look bad). Just saying because the question is about Microsoft Reciprocal License (Ms-RL). Take care.