# Ms-RL License - clarification?

Tags: licensing

We have an `asp.net` website project that we are distributing to subsidiary companies.

We are also referencing a `ms-RL's licensed` module( **dll**  , which we didn't built , it's on the web.) .

[The MS-RL information states :](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/openness/licenses.aspx#MRL)

> Reciprocal Grants- For any **file** you distribute that contains code from
>   the software (in source code or binary format), you must provide
>   recipients the **source code to that file along with a copy of this
>   license**, which license will govern that file. You may license other
>   files that are entirely your own work and do not contain code from the
>   software under any terms you choose.

**Question**

I find it not crystal clear :

If we have `MyPage.aspx` that reference  `JSON_MS_RL.DLL` :

According to Ms-RL - *Which* source code  we  would have to supply ?

- Mypage.aspx ?
- JSON_MS_RL.DLL ? ( it's binary  , but I assume the source code is needed)

Comment: Why did you tag the question [gpl], while it was not mentioned in the text? Is your project covered by GNU GPL? If so, you cannot use library under MS-RL, since MS-RL is a copyleft license that is [incompatible](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#ms-rl) with GNU GPL.

Comment: Crossposting detected: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20141002055253AAKGJru

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491099/ms-rl-explanation-needed

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov the dup is not telling which sources I need to include. and the amazon answer says both. so there is a problem here

Comment: @PaulCrovella  **Did I ask for an advice** ?I dont see how it relates to legal advice. it's about clarifying software usage. you want me to provide you with how many licensing question there are in SO ?

Comment: @PaulCrovella No. I just asked how it works. I didnt ask any advice.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I just supplied an imaginary drill where there is a file and a ms-rl dll referenced. and since I didn't understand the description of the ms-rl license - I just asked which source of files ( according to my sample) I would have to supply to clients ? ( the ms-rl original code OR my page code which sues ms-rl dll OR both).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed seems to be a quite obscure passage. The problem is that the word ‘file’ is not defined, while its meaning is not obvious at all. As far as I understand you, the only ‘file’ where the library and the your own code combine together is a distribution / installation package. Does that count as single ‘file’ under Ms-RL? If does, does it counts if I would archive Ms-RL-covered software along with something else into mere `*.tar.gz`. If that does, it goes beyond all reasons.

I am not a lawyer to interpret it, so the only thing I can do is to refer to some explanation, that can be found over the Web.

The Code Project (that is Microsoft-oriented network for programmers) [summarizes the terms of Ms-RL in that way](http://www.codeproject.com/info/Licenses.aspx) (enumeration mine):

> A Microsoft open license and a free software license. Allows for distribution of derived code so long as the modified source files are included and retain the Ms-RL.
>
> 1. Provides copyright protection: True
> 2. Can be used in commercial applications: True
> 3. Bug fixes / extensions must be released to the public domain: False
> 4. Provides an explicit patent license: True
> 5. Can be used in proprietary (closed source) applications: True
> 6. Is a viral licence: False

You are interested in ⑤, which is clear, and ⑥, which might require further explanation: ‘viral’ is a derogatory term for such a license that allows derivative works but forces to release them under terms of the same license.

So, according to The Code Project, you have to provide sources of Ms-RL-covered library only (either modified or not), not of your whole project. Trust that opinion on your own risk, of course.

Comment: PArdon me , but please look at my understanding : _For any **file(#1)** you distribute **that contains code** from the software (in source code or binary format), you must provide recipients the source code **to that file** along with a copy of this license, which license will govern that file_ ---- so if I have a page (file #1) that reference DLL which is ms-rl , Then I must provide the source code to that file!!! which is my file !!!! not the ms-rl file/library !........am I wrong ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Sorry, I cannot judge whether you are right or wrong. But if I were you I would for sure try to avoid software under marginal licenses, such as Ms-RL, in production.

Even if you would understand it correctly (perhaps, with the help of a lawyer), the author of library (copyright holder, to be precise) could have been misunderstanding it, so he might try to make a claim relying on his invalid interpretation.

Maybe, there is an alternative to that library under some clear and common free software license (Expat/X11, GNU LGPL, Apache v2, etc)?

Comment: Reading it 20 times  I think there need to be a clarification of `TO VS OF` : _For any file you distribute that contains code from the software (in source code or binary format), you must provide recipients the source code **to(or of ???)** that file_.......

Comment: @RoyiNamir I am not sure, I got your point about ‘to’ vs. ‘of’; but if want to turn clarification of licence to clarification of certain word, that would definitely be the word ‘file’.

Comment: @RoyiNamir As far as I understand you, the first ‘level’ of ‘file’ where the library and the your own code combine together is a distribution / installation package. Does that count as single ‘file’ under Ms-RL? If does, does it counts if I would archive Ms-RL-covered software along with something else into mere `*.tar.gz`. If *that* does, it goes beyond all reasons. That’s exactly why I would avoid this licence – it’s obscure and Microsoft does not care to explain it.